# Basic questions on how to structire code in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, model-view-controller

I'm very new to Symfony and have a very basic question.

So I have my Symfony-Project with a default-controller and some other controllers. In my base-template there is a body-block and a category-block (which is my site-navigation).

How would I now buld my application so that the category-tree is only readed and build once?

I mean, when I fetch the categories from the DB in the default-controller, they are shown on my default-page. But how do I get them on the other pages, too?

Do I have to build them in every controller in every method??? that can't be it, so how would I do that in this mvc?

Comment: Most issues you come across have already been dealt with, which means there are usually one or more bundles you can use to sove the problem. https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenuBundle

Comment: For basic structure and usage I suggest you just read through the documentation, it's actually quite good http://symfony.com/doc/current/index.html

Comment: If you do end up with some code you need across your application you could just add it to a service and then inject that service into the controllers that need it. Ie `$categories = $this->categoryService->getAll();`

Comment: I agree with @JimL . If you want reach that categories from every page, then you can go with creating a category service and / or creating a twig function.

Comment: Using services-oriented approach is good for code reusability is good practice. But before, you should know that each request is relative to a route+  controller action. Then, inside each controller where you need the category tree, you will need to inject the service responsible for fetching. Fetching  and building once can be done via other techniques like caching (which can be involved in different steps of the request-response process)

Comment: Hi and thank you for the answers. I'm trying now out the servie-container like described in [link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html). I have defined the `AppBundle\Menu` in the YAML and instance it in my controller `$menu = $this->get('app.menu');` I get a **The autoloader expected class "AppBundle\Menu" to be defined in file "D:\xamp\htdocs\icp/src\AppBundle\Menu.php". The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or namespace probably has a typo.** .. but there IS a  `class Menu {
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controller embedding is an elegant solution for this problem. It could be done this way:

1. Create a controller that renders your category tree. Let's call it *categoryTreeAction*. The output should contain only the widget's code, not the whole page.
2. Call the *render* function at the appropiate place in the Twig template:

   {{ render(controller('AppBundle:Default:categoryTree') }}

Hint: you can also use controller parameters for passing context variables (for example to highlight the active category).

Take a look at the documentation for more info:
 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers